# excluding certain directories gulp-inject

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-inject

Ignoring `bower_components` while including `css` and `javascript` files

```
gulp.task('files', function(){
    var target = gulp.src("./client/index.html");
    var sources = gulp.src(["./client/**/*.js", "./client/**/*.css"], {read: false});

    target.pipe(inject(sources))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./client"))    
});
```

I don't want to include `client/bower_components` in my index.html? Is there a way i can specify what files to include in my `sources`?

https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#optionsignorepath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exclude the `bower_components` like this.

```
var sources = gulp.src(["!./client/bower_components/**/*"
                 "./client/**/*.js", "./client/**/*.css"], {read: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the order matters. For example, let's say I have a `tests` folder inside of my `client` folder where all the client-side code lives.  I don't want to include my specs in the `index.html` I am generating.

Originally I had

```
var sources = gulp.src([
    '!./client/tests/**/*', // exclude the specs up front, didn't work
    './client/config/app.js',
    './client/config/*.js',
    './client/**/*.js', // conflicts with the tests exclusion   
    './client/**/*.css'
], {read: false});
```

but it was still injecting the specs into my html! The problem was that I was telling gulp to include all of the `client` folders **AFTER** I told it to exclude one of the `client` folders. So I just had to put the excluded folder at the end to fix the issue.

```
var sources = gulp.src([
    './client/config/app.js',
    './client/config/*.js',
    './client/**/*.js',
    './client/**/*.css',
    '!./client/tests/**/*' // exclude the specs at the end, works!
], {read: false});
```